# Looking for How-To-Guid for concise steps on creating a 64 bit installer

Tags: wix

After flailing around for days trying to create a hybrid installer ( System.Data.Sqlite.dll is either 32 bit or 64 bit the rest of my C# program is cpu agnostic) I decided to do it the proper way and build 2 separate Wix installers.  I'm surprised there is not a section in the Wix 3.5 online help, under How To Guides, on how to set all the proper attributes to create a 64 bit installer.  I've stumbled upon the Win64 attribute on Componenet and then read the 'light' errors saying the Template Summary property is not set correctly.  I finally tracked this down to the Platform attribute on Product, I think.

Flame on!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't require setting a lot of attributes: http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/05/14/working-hard-or-hardly-working/

Comment: Changing two is a must, and my next problem is the ICE80 error saying, "This 64BitComponent BlahBlah uses 32BitDirectory INSTALLLOCATION.  I haven't quite figured out where this gets set to Program Files x86.

Comment: BTW this link is must reading and includes link to example code with great preprocessor examples referenced in joyofsetup post. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/08/09/4317654.aspx